# Pgfplot : problem with common exponent for ticklabels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have plotted 2 similar graphs with Tikz Pgfplot and I am not able to explain why their axes tick labels are not rendered the same way : both use exponent scientific notation (which is what I want), but the first one uses it for *every* tick while the second one uses one common exponent for the whole axis.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newlength{\figurewidth}
\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\setlength{\figurewidth}{0.29\textwidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=0.79058756\figurewidth,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,    xmax=0.00085,
xlabel={$a$},
ymin=0,    ymax=0.551,
ylabel={},
title={Example 1},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
]
\addplot [color=blue,dashed,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{3.9648287e-17 0\\
7.1951505e-07   0.0020036364\\
0.00067324963   0.551\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=0.79058756\figurewidth,
scale only axis,
xmin=-5e-07,    xmax=2.7e-06,
xlabel={$b$},
ymin=0,    ymax=0.551,
ylabel={},
title={Example 2},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
]
\addplot [color=blue,dashed,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{0 0\\
2.7092763e-06   0.40273091\\
8.2017385e-08   0.551\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

And here is the result:

[image: Graphs with different axis display]

One can notice the difference in the display of x axis between left and right. Does anybody have an explanation ? How to get the display of the second figure for both cases ? I have tried many combinations of options but I couldn't find anything satisfactory. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Using PGFPlots 1.11 (TeX Live 2014 with updates) I cannot reproduce this issue: "Example 1" has a common exponent on the x axis.

Comment: Same here. Works fine for me with TeXLive2014 and TeXLive2013.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an outdated TeX distro which is resolved by updating the packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, mvkorpel and Peter Grill. Actually I was using TeXLive2012 on my Debian distribution. It works fine with later versions I tested on other systems.